# How do I preserve a column name when looping through a data table in R?

Tags: r, loops, lapply

I am trying to preserve a column name in R when looping through columns, in this case I want to extract each data set with the relevant column to perform operations. I am unsure how to keep the name. At the moment I am getting the column labeled as "v3" when using `get()?`

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

month_date = c("2019-01-01", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-03")
num_cars = c(100,201,168)
num_planes = c(10,15,17)

df = data.frame(month_date, num_cars, num_planes)
setDT(df)

names(df)[2:3] %>%
  lapply(function(m) {
    
    my_new_df = df[,.(month_date,num_cars,get(m))]
    
  })

[[1]]
   month_date num_cars  V3
1: 2019-01-01      100 100
2: 2019-01-02      201 201
3: 2019-01-03      168 168

[[2]]
   month_date num_cars V3
1: 2019-01-01      100 10
2: 2019-01-02      201 15
3: 2019-01-03      168 17
```

Answer (score 1):

The combination of `lapply`, `dplyr` and `data.table` is a little bit odd here, but if you really want this output you can just modify as below:

```r
names(df)[2:3] %>%
  lapply(function(m) {
    
    my_new_df = df[,.(month_date,num_cars,my_var=get(m))]
    setnames(my_new_df, "my_var", m)
    
  })
```